# For which values of $p,q$ does the integral $\int_0^1 x^p (\ln\frac{1}{x})^qdx$ converge?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

For which values of $p,q$ does the integral $\int_0^1 x^p (\ln\frac{1}{x})^qdx$ converge?

I use the substitution $t=1/x$ to obtain this better looking integral: $\int_1^\infty \frac{(\ln t)^q}{t^{p+2}}$. Integration by parts gives me a recurence formula for the integral, but $p,q$ are not necessarily integers so I don't think that's the right approach.

Comment: Hint: $(\ln t)^q/t^{2p} > 1/t^{2p}$ for all $t$, while $(\ln t)^q/t^{2p} < 1/t^{2p-\epsilon}$ when $t$ is large. Use comparison tests.

Comment: The substitution leads me to $I_{p,q}=\int_1^\infty\frac{\left(\log{t}\right)^q}{t^{p+2}}dt$. The the comparison test as suggested by @Greg Martin

Comment: @marwalix, thanks for the correction!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

$e^{1/x}>1+1/x \implies1/x>\ln(1+1/x)>\ln(1/x),\:\:x>0.$

$$\int_0^1 x^p\ln^q(1/x)dx\le\int_0^1x^{p-q}dx\\\int_c^dx^{p-q}\le\large\sigma_{\normalsize p,q}\normalsize=\frac{1}{1+p-q}\cdot (1-c^{1+p-q}),\:\:0<c<d<1;\:p\ne q-1\\\forall p>q-1,\:\:\:\lim_{c\to 0^+}\large\sigma_{\normalsize p,q}<\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

By substituting $x=\frac{1}{t}$ so $dx=-\frac{1}{t^2}dt$ and the integral reads as follows

$$I_{p,q}=\int_1^\infty\frac{\left(\log{t}\right)^q}{t^{p+2}}dt$$

The interesting bound is $\infty$. If $p\gt -1$ the integral is convergent because the integrand is $o(t^{-p-2})$ and if $p\leq -1$ it is divergent because the integrand is larger than $t^{-p-2+\epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon\gt 0$ In the neighborhood of $\infty$

Comment: What about $q$? The answer says that both have to be greater than -1. Thanks a lot for the answer, but I'm not suppose to use $o$. Is there any other way?

Comment: yes just use comparaison. Forget $o$ and use the fact that the integrand is $\lt t^{-p-2}$. I am sorry but I think we do not care about $q$

Comment: But if $q=-1$ we have a new problem on $1$, and I also don't get why (\ln t)^q/t^{2p} < 1/t^{2p}...I think that inequality is true for the case $q<0$...

Answer (score 1):

I understand this is a bit late.

But we can substitute $x=e^{-t}$ to make the integral nice looking: $$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-(p+1)t}t^q}dt$$
We can split this into $I_1=\int_{0}^{1}{e^{-(p+1)t}t^q}dt$ and $I_2=\int_{1}^{\infty}{e^{-(p+1)t}t^q}dt$.

$I_1$ converges for $q>-1$ (LCT with $t^q$).

Now for $q>-1$, we consider $I$. The only point of concern is $\infty$.

1. $p < -1: e^{-(p+1)t}t^q\rightarrow \infty$ as $x \rightarrow \infty \implies I$ diverges
2. $p = -1: I=\int_{0}^{\infty}t^qdt$ diverges for $q>-1$
3. $p > -1: \int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-(p+1)t}t^q}dt=\frac{1}{(p+1)^q}\Gamma(q+1)$ converges.

Thus $I$ converges for $p>-1, q>-1$.

Answer (score 0):

After substituting $x=\frac{1}{t}$, you can use two comparison test to check for divergence near 1, when $q<0$:

1. Use the limit comparison test with $ln(t)^{q}$ - the limit is 1, so both of them will converge or diverge together
   $$ \lim \limits_{t\to 1} \frac{\frac{ln(t)^q}{t^{p+2}}}{ln(t)^{q}} = \lim \limits_{t\to 1} \frac{1}{t^{p+2}} =1 $$
2. Use the limit comparison test between $ln(t)^{q}$ and $(t-1)^q$:
   $$ \lim \limits_{t\to 1} \frac{ln(t)^{q}}{(t-1)^q} = \lim \limits_{t\to 1} 
    (\frac{ln(t)}{(t-1)})^q $$
   and since 
   $$\lim \limits_{t\to 1} \frac{ln(t)}{(t-1)} = \lim \limits_{t\to 1} \frac{\frac{1}{t}}{1} = 1$$
   you'll get that those two will also diverge/converge together. Since $\int_{1}^{a}\frac{1}{(t-1)^{-q}}dt$ will only converge if $-q<1 \Rightarrow q>-1$, the original integral will also converge.